# Grep Regular-Expressions on more lines

Tags: shell, grep

Dear all, I am writing a python program that is retrieving edifact log messages from a .gz file...
An example of 2 logs are the following:

```
2009/03/02 12:13:59.642396 siamp102 mux1-30706 Trace name: MSG
Message sent [con=251575 (APEOBEinMux1), len=2106, CorrID=000182C42DE0ED]
UNB+IATB:1+1ASRPFA+1A0APE+090302:1213+0095JQOL2

2009/03/02 12:14:00.029496 siamp102 mux1-30706 Trace name: MSG
Message sent [con=737 (APIV2_1), len=22370, CorrID=000182C42DE0ED]
UNB+IATB:1+1ASIFQLFS+1ARIOFS+090302:1214+0122V11ON9
```

I would like to write a regular expression able to match some field from the first line, some from the second and some other from the third ...

Is there any way to write a regular expression to be used with GREP that matches field from consecutive lines ??

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Aargh, this question is not rendering properly in Firefox 3.1b2. It's ultra-wide, extending far to the right and making the entire page get a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I've noticed it ... I'll modify the text immediately

Comment: Same problem in 3.0.7 on Mac OS 10.5 intel

Comment: Now it's more clear ...
Each Log has 3 lines and is divided from the following by a blank line !
I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `grep` alone, I think this is not possible. I would suggest `awk` or `perl` in order to be able to save some context from previous lines.

In `perl` this gives something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$isInLogSection = 'NO';
while (<>) {
    if ( /siamp102/ ) {
        # Start of log section: retrieve its ID
        $isInLogSection = 'YES';
        split;
        $logSectionID = $_[0];
    }

    if ($isInLogSection eq YES && /len=/) {
        # Retrieve value of len
        ...
    }

    if ( /^$/ ) {
        # End of log section
        $isInLogSection = 'NO';
    }
}
```

In `awk` this gives something like:

```
BEGIN { isInLogSection = "NO"; }
/siamp102/ { isInLogSection = "YES"; logSectionID = $1; }
/len=/ { if (isInLogSection == "YES") { #retrieve len value } }
/^$/ { isInLogSection = "NO" }
```

I am not 100% certain of the exact syntax. This is mainly a canvas for illustrating the principles.

Comment: Can u please suggest me the syntax for the awk command able to select some element form first, second and third line ? Thanks

Comment: Oops sorry, when you added your comment I was editing my answer with a perl example...

Answer (score 1):

Check this previous thread, you might get the answer you're looking for: [bash grep newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228248/bash-grep-newline)

See the `pcregrep` answer, `pcregrep -M` allows multiple lines to match.