# bash grep newline

Tags: bash, grep

[**Editorial insertion**: Possible duplicate of the same poster's [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083601/reading-a-subset-of-the-lines-in-a-text-file-with-bash)?]

Hi, I need to extract from the file:

```
first
second
third
```

using the grep command, the following line:

```
second
third
```

How should the grep command look like?

Comment: Do you mean this literally or do you mean that you want the second and third line, no matter what content they have? Also, is this your homework?

Comment: Not my homework, just a task. I don't know exactly how to construct a regular expression here.

Comment: What I want is to construct a regular expression that will contain a newline character.

Comment: `grep` is inherently line-oriented. You don't need a regular expression to match the literal string 'first' or 'second'. Let me ask again: do you want to match those exact words or do you want to match this: the second line + the third line (without regard to content)? If you want to match two specific lines, then one of Liori's solutions would be better than `grep`. Please try to explain what you want more clearly.

Comment: I want to search in the file for a sequence of lines for ex "line1\nline2".

Comment: If you want to search for a sequence of lines and you want to add words to the file, then `grep` isn't the right tool. It sounds more like a job for a scripting language to me, but again without a better description of the real problem, it's impossible to help you. Please edit your question and show (1) reasonably realistic data and (2) a more complete explanation of what you want to do with the file.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of `grep`, you can use `pcregrep` which supports multiline patterns

```
pcregrep -M 'second\nthird' file
```

`-M` allows the pattern to match more than one line.

Comment: You may want to use `\s+` in place of `\n` depending on the line endings in the file (some might be `\r\n`)

Answer (score 9):

Your question abstract "bash grep newline", implies that you would want to match on the `second\nthird` sequence of characters - i.e. something containing newline within it.

Since the grep works on "lines" and these two are different lines, you would not be able to match it this way.

So, I'd split it into several tasks:

1. you match the line that contains "second" and output the line that has matched and the subsequent line:

   ```
   grep -A 1 "second" testfile
   ```
2. you translate every other newline into the sequence that is guaranteed not to occur in the  input. I think the simplest way to do that would be using perl:

   ```
   perl -npe '$x=1-$x; s/\n/##UnUsedSequence##/ if $x;'
   ```
3. you do a grep on these lines, this time searching for string `##UnUsedSequence##third`:

   ```
   grep "##UnUsedSequence##third"
   ```
4. you unwrap the unused sequences back into the newlines, sed might be the simplest:

   ```
   sed -e 's/##UnUsedSequence##/\n'
   ```

So the resulting pipe command to do what you want would look like:

```
grep -A 1 "second" testfile | perl -npe '$x=1-$x; s/\n/##UnUsedSequence##/ if $x;' | grep "##UnUsedSequence##third" | sed -e 's/##UnUsedSequence##/\n/'
```

Not the most elegant by far, but should work. I'm curious to know of better approaches, though - there should be some.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think **grep** is the way to go on this.

If you just want to strip the first line from any file (to generalize your question), I would use **sed** instead.

```
sed '1d' INPUT_FILE_NAME
```

This will send the contents of the file to standard output with the first line deleted.

Then you can redirect the standard output to another file to capture the results.

```
sed '1d' INPUT_FILE_NAME > OUTPUT_FILE_NAME
```

That should do it.

If you have to use **grep** and just don't want to display the line with *first* on it, then try this:

```
grep -v first INPUT_FILE_NAME
```

By passing the **-v** switch, you are telling **grep** to show you everything **but** the expression that you are passing. In effect show me everything but the line(s) with *first* in them.

However, the downside is that a file with multiple *first*'s in it will not show those other lines either and may not be the behavior that you are expecting.

To shunt the results into a new file, try this:

```
grep -v first INPUT_FILE_NAME > OUTPUT_FILE_NAME
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you may have your last two examples backwards.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what do you want to match. I would not use grep, but one of the following:

```
tail -2 file         # to get last two lines
head -n +2 file      # to get all but first line
sed -e '2,3p;d' file # to get lines from second to third
```

(not sure how standard it is, it works in GNU tools for sure)

Answer (score 1):

Line? Or lines?

Try

```
grep -E -e '(second|third)' filename
```

**Edit:** grep is line oriented. you're going to have to use either Perl, sed or awk to perform the pattern match across lines.

BTW -E tell grep that the regexp is extended RE.

Comment: Lines. But what about constructing a regular expression that will be used by egrep? How the new line character is represented?

Comment: `egrep 'second\\nthird' filename`

Answer (score 1):

So you just don't want the line containing "first"?  `-v` inverts the grep results.

```
$ echo -e "first\nsecond\nthird\n" | grep -v first
second
third
```

Answer (score 1):

grep -A1 "second" | grep -B1 "third" works nicely, and if you have multiple matches it will even get rid of the original -- match delimiter

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '(second|third)' /path/to/file
egrep -w 'second|third' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
$ grep -1 third filename
```

this will print a string with match and one string before and after. Since "third" is in the last string you get last two strings.

Answer (score 0):

I like [notnoop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1229129/623735), but building on [AndrewY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228397/623735) (which is better for those without pcregrep, but way too complicated), you can just do:

```
RESULT=`grep -A1 -s -m1 '^\s*second\s*$' file | grep -s -B1 -m1 '^\s*third\s*$'`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v '^first' filename
```

Where the -v flag inverts the match.