# finding contents of one file in another in Unix

Tags: bash, file, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to search for the contents of one file(f1) in another file(f2) and print successful matches.
I have tried various posted answers as shown below but none of them help.

1.
`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++}FNR!=NR && !a[$0]{print}' f1 f2`

2.

```
while read name
do
awk '$1 ~ '$name'' f2| awk '{print $NF, $4}' >> f3
done < f1
```

3.
`grep -F -f f1 f2 > f3`

All the above solutions print non matching entries also from f2. Is there any other way of doing it?

I am looking forward to an exact match in my scenario.
Say for example

$cat f1
abc
def
ghi

$cat f2
this line has abc
bc
abc
de
this line has ghi
i
ghi

Expected output :
abc
ghi

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To better understand your question can you provide some input output examples

Comment: I understand that as: Read one file (f1) into a variable, find and print all exact matches of the contents of that variable in file (f2) (complete with newlines etc.), For that, `pcregrep` seems to be able to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1229129/1705441

Comment: Are you looking for the `-x` flag of `grep`? Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Do you want to match on strings or regular expressions (e.g. does `.` mean a literal period character or does it mean `any character`)? Do you want to match whole words or partial (e.g. does `the` match `there` or not)? Does case matter (e.g. does `the` match `The` or not)? If you want full "word" matches only - what's a word (e.g. is it alphabetic strings only, delimited by some set of characters or something else)? Edit your question to show a few lines containing the DIFFICULT cases to handle and the expected output or you're going to get a solution that works for the simple cases only.

Comment: Input may contain alphanumeric characters as well as special characters and each line in f1 is supposed to be considered as a string to be looked up in f2.

Comment: Found a solution.  while read string; do grep "^$string" f2; done < f1

Comment: @user3910974 that's not even in the ballpark of a solution. It will fail in many ways for many different character and string combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Try below command (-i) flag is to search case insensitive

```
grep -i -Fx -f search_this.txt search_in.txt
```

Demo session is below

```
$ cat search_this.txt
xxxx yyyy
kkkkkk
zzzzzzzz

$ cat search_in.txt
line doesnot contain any name
This person is xxxx yyyy good
xxxx yyyy
Another line which doesnot contain any name
Is kkkkkk a good name ?
kkkkkk
This name itself is sleeping ...zzzzzzzz
I can't find any other name
Lets try the command now

$ grep -i -Fx -f search_this.txt search_in.txt
xxxx yyyy
kkkkkk
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But my expected output from your given solution would be blank since no line in "search_in.txt" exactly matches any entry from "search_this.txt". I am looking forward to an exact match.

Comment: For exact match use the command "comm" with option -1 and -2 .. it will list all lines which are common in both files....try it

Comment: AFter seeing your expected result in the question modified the answer ... use the -Fx flag to search for fixed string... it matches your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

For me, that works, but I'm unsure if this is safe from a variable expansion point of view

```
PATTERN=`cat f1`; pcregrep -M "$PATTERN" f2
```

---

For using f2 as a number of patterns each which should be found, a solution seems to be here: [finding contents of one file into another file in unix shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059422)